# CodeConversion from byte to int

Tags: java, string

chr[k]=byte(chp[i]-chq[j]); //problem

The problem comes in type conversion. I have seen various answers to this and when implementing this it could not be solved.
How to remove Syntex error in the above code

Comment: Java uses C-style casting syntax.

Comment: Okay but How can i correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ((byte)some expression) instead of byte(some expression).

Comment: Thanku MirMasej,edited the code user3062946 copy paste error were dere sorry

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compare the numerical difference (char by char) between two equal length strings? I'm sorry but your explanation of the problem left much to be desired.

If I were trying to solve the issue of comparing the numerical difference between two strings, I would likely come up with something like this:

```
    char[] a = "cd".toCharArray();
    char[] b = "aa".toCharArray();

    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (a.length == b.length && i < a.length)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i])
            sum += (a[i]-b[i]);
        else 
            sum += (b[i])-a[i];

        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Total character difference: " + sum);
```

This should cover all cases... Assuming I correctly understood what you were asking.

Comment: Yes,but what is the problem in my code(type conversion specifically)

Comment: I don't see any problem with the type conversion... but you're doing the same arithmetic in your if and else cases. Shouldn't you be doing `chr[k]=byte(chq[i]-chp[j]);` in the `else` case?

Comment: Additionally, in the case where the bytes are equal, you're setting `ch[k]=0`, I assume you mean to set `chr[k]=0`... Also you're not incrementing `i` in the `else` case of your loop